# Spring Data MongoDB with text index: difference between matchingany and matchingphrase

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, full-text-indexing

I am using MongoDB and Spring for an application

I am using a text index on my collection.

I found two methods:

- `matchingany`
- `matchingphrase`

But I am unable to understand the difference.

Please help me to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a match on multiple words forming a phrase then use `matchingPhrase`, if you want a match on at least one word in a ist of words then use `matchingAny`.

For example, given these documents (and assuming the `title` attribute is text-indexed):

```
{ "id": 1, "title": "The days of the week"}
{ "id": 2, "title": "Once a week"}
{ "id": 3, "title": "Once a month"}
```

- `matchingAny("Once")` will match the documents with id=2 and id=3
- `matchingAny("month", "foo' , "bar")` will match the document with id=3
- `matchingPhrase("The days of the week")` will match the document with id=1

More details [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/TextCriteria.html).